# Update in child model of one parent to trigger change in another model Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In my rails 4 application I have the following models

```
Class User
  has_many :user_buckets
  has_many :buckets, through: :user_buckets, dependent: :destroy
end
Class Bucket
  has_many :user_buckets, after_add: :update_event_bucket_participants, after_remove: :update_event_bucket_participants
  has_many :users, through: :user_buckets, dependent: :destroy
end
Class UserBucket
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bucket
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :bucket_id
end
class Event
  has_many :event_buckets
  has_many :buckets, :through => :event_buckets
end

class EventBucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :bucket
  after_commit :update_event_partcipants

  has_many :event_participants, dependent: :destroy

  def update_event_partcipants    
    bucket_users = Bucket.find_by_id(self.bucket_id).users
    bucket_users.each do |user|
      self.event_participants.create(user_id: user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

Where a single user can be in multiple buckets and we can attach multiple buckets to an event.

I am facing a issue here is when I add/remove a user from a bucket after that bucket is added to an event, it is not correctly working. I mean any updates in bucket after the event is created with that specific bucket not reflecting the changes.

I tried using **after_add** callback in **Bucket** model but still having the same issue.

What else should I do to solve this problem? What I am missing here?

Comment: Where is the update_event_bucket_participants defined?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this would work, but what if you change:

The `Bucket` appears to be the join model between `Users` and `Events`, it can hold many users and many events?

```
class Bucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_buckets
  has_many :users, through: :user_buckets

  has_many :event_buckets
  has_many :events, through: :event_buckets
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_buckets
  has_many :buckets, through: :user_buckets

  has_many :events, through: :user_buckets
end

class UserBucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :bucket
  has_many :events, through: :bucket

  validates :user_id, :uniqueness => { :scope => :bucket_id }
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_buckets
  has_many :buckets, through: :event_buckets

  has_many :users, through: :event_buckets
end

class EventBucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :bucket
  has_many :users, through: :bucket

  validates :event_id, :bucket_id, presence: true
end
```

This way you can get all users by doing `Event.find(1).users` and you would get all attending through the join models. No need to create the `EventParticipant`, unless you have a lot of information saved there, in which case you should change the rest of the modeling.

Comment: Thanks for your response davidwessman. Yes. We need to save status of each users in bucket added for that event. I mean for a particular event we need to save status of each users in that bucket. So we created intermediate table **event_participants"